# SoapUI adds '\r\n' when expands large property

Tags: soapui

I'm using SoapUI 5.4.0 community edition SOAP, Windows 10:

I've defined a variable in the test case like:

```
def byte[] war  = Base64.getMimeEncoder().encode(raw.toByteArray());
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('war', new String(war));
```

Later on i POST to a Rest service with the following Json content:

```
...

    "content": "${#TestCase#war}",
...
```

The request fails with a 400 'bad request', the HTTP logs writes:

> ```
> Tue Apr 30 08:30:25 CEST 2019:DEBUG:>> "    "content": 'PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPGZlOkZhY3R1cmFlIHhtbG5z[\r][\n]"
> Tue Apr 30 08:30:25 CEST 2019:DEBUG:>> "OmZlPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LmZhY3R1cmFlLmdvYi5lcy9mb3JtYXRvL1ZlcnNpb25lcy9GYWN0dXJh[\r][\n]"
> ```

Can those CR LF cause the request to fail? How would i instruct SoapUI not to add them if so?

Answer (score 0):

Not using Base64 MIME enconder solved the issue